# How to properly organize work with database connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, digital-ocean, ruby-on-rails-6, postgresql-11

I have a Rails application that I've been developing for quite some time. All this time I tested it locally and on a DEV server. On the DEV server, next to the deployed application, there is also a PG database. And there were no problems with connections. I think there is simply no connection limit, or it is too high - not so important.

Today I started doing deployment to the PROD server. It is similar in power to that for DEV, but BD is already in the DO Database. By the way, the servers themselves are also located in DigitalOcean.

The problem is that DO Database has a limit of 20 connections. And as far as I understand, exceeding this limit - the Rails application gives an error:

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections)

The most obvious option is to reduce the number of requests on page load. But this still did not solve the problem if, for example, the number of users increases.

Can you please tell me which way to look? Are there any solutions to the problem other than updating the DO Database power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [PG Bouncer](https://medium.com/engineering-housing/pg-bouncer-and-ruby-on-rails-8b8c027f45ba) (never tried it though, so i can't really tell how it will impact the app).

Comment: PGBouncer helped